# Comparing objects in Cocoa with compare:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sorting

I noticed that `NSString` understands the message `compare:` but I couldn't fin much info about the generic mechanism of comparing objects in Cocoa. What classes implement `compare:`? Is this some sort of `protocol`?

I need this to implement something similar to `Smalltalk's` `OrderedCollection`: an array that is always kept sorted.

Thanks advance!

Comment: Not an answer about `compare:`, but: you can use the `-indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:` method with `NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex` to maintain a sorted `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track that `compare:` is present on some classes and is used for sorting, but it's not a standard part of any protocol. (`-isEqual:` on the other hand, is required by `NSObject` and thus exists on nearly everything.)

You can sort a collection by telling the collection to sort its contents via the `compare:` method on each item:

```
[myMutableArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

If you implement a comparison method on your own classes, then it should accept an object of the same class, and return `NSOrderedAscending`, `NSOrderedDescending`, or `NSOrderedSame` as appropriate.

The method's existence isn't standardized because its semantics can't really be standardized. Many objects can be "compared" in multiple ways, depending on what you want. Even strings have both a `compare:` and a `caseInsensitiveCompare:` and lots of other locale-dependent options, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

All this said, use `compare:` when it works for you, but it dates back to early ObjC and there are also block-based mechanisms to use for sorting in many of the custom comparison cases that you might find simpler.

Comment: OK, so there's no standard / default way of comparing objects: I must check if the compared objects respond to compare:. Is this correct?

Comment: @cfisher: Yes, that's correct; exposing a `-compare:` method is an informal standard if you like. I assume you mean "check" as in check the documentation-- there'd be little value in checking at runtime since you'll already know what types are in your collections and how you wish to compare them. Typically the Foundation classes which are naturally sortable will have this method or methods (`NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate` come to mind), and you can of course add similar to your own classes as desired.

Comment: @cfisher: (And again, note that essentially all classes you'll deal with (and create, in theory) expose an `-isEqual:` method if you need to compare for *equivalence*, which is far more generically definable concept.)